# Is zero a non-divisible $\mathbb Z$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, injective-module

I want to find two injective $\mathbb Z$-modules for which the tensor product is not injective, so i used to try $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, which is equal to zero, so... Is it true? 
Since $\mathbb Z$ is a PID being injective over it is equivalent to being divisible...

Comment: Well...yes: the trivial group is trivially a divisible (abelian) group...ir in fact: *no*, zero is **not** a *non-divisible* abelian group.

Comment: Oh thanks, you are right, z is a pid so....

Comment: Can you please help me to find such an example?

Comment: There is no such example: if $M$ is any abelian group and $D$ is any divisible abelian group, then $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}D$ is divisible.

Comment: No i want to find an exaple of injective R-modules for which the tensor product is not injective...

Comment: But over Z injective was the same as divisible